# How to know which evernote server I am logged in?

Tags: evernote

Below is my issue:

1. I log in evernote from my browser and create a notebook named "Web Notebook"
2. I log in evernote from my phone, I cannot see this "Web Notebook". I am in China but I select "Evernote International Server" rather than "Yinxiang Server". And, I create a notebook named "Second Notebook" via my phone.
3. Some time later, I log in evernote from my browser again and can see "Second Notebook" but I cannot find "Web Notebook" any more
4. I run Evernote SDK Demo. Whether or not I do setLocale(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE) when EvernoteSession.Builder(this), I only can see "Web Notebook"
5. For now, I cannot find "Web Notebook" from Evernote web/PC/phone any more but I can see it 100% via Evernote SDK demo. Of course, in this demo, I cannot see "Second Notebook"

   -- This really confuse me. I want to know which evernote server I am working on. Thank you for reading my question and any comments are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the SDKs always talk to the "international" Evernote service. setLocale will only change the language. For using Evernote in the browser, www.evernote.com is the international service, and app.yinxiang.com is the YXBJ (china) service.

Comment: Thanks a lot, akhaku, I find the reason is that my SDK is connecting to evernote sandbox but not production.